# JPA: Persist TemporalType.TIME using hibernate

Tags: hibernate, jpa, jpa-2.0

When I try to use Calendar as object storing my time

```
@Temporal(TemporalType.TIME)
Calendar pullServiceStart = getNewTimeInstance(0,0);
```

... I get the error message "Calendar cannot persist TIME".

Now, java.util.date is deprecated but what I need is to store a time object only containing minutes and hours.

How to handle that?

Comment: Java 8? LocalDate.now()?

Comment: Sorry, I am using Java7

Answer (score 0):

`Calendar` cannot persist time only. If you cannot switch to java 8 and its `LocalTime`:

```
  @Column(name="local_time")
  private LocalTime localTime;
```

The only option is to switch from `Calendar` to `Date`.